# Nodejs read image from server with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I already found some posts regarding on how to send an image to a client with nodejs. However the in the backend I get the image from another url, where I need to pass an authentification header.

From the client, I want to access the response and the image what so ever, but this doesn't seem to work, as the response only shows the image binary encoded.

Any solutions to this? Or how would you access an image that is user:password protected on the server (so a basic auth header is required for that)

Comment: could you show us some of your code?

Comment: what is the module behind `request`?

Comment: It's request, from node

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: It works ok, I just can't access it on the UI from a promise based request, only from direct url

Comment: ok. could you show us the promise based request?

Comment: It's swagger based

Comment: Do you process/alter the image on your server. If not you can perhaps pipe the response stream of the other service to your server's response